# How to search where some data is in table 1 and other data is in table 3 with both having a UUID the same

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables

For instance

```
Salestable
-ID
-variableB
-customerUUID
-variableC

Customertable
-customerUUID
-contractUUID

Contracttable
-contractUUID
-variableD
```

So I am currently doing a SQL Query on salestable

Like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT variableB FROM Salestable WHERE variableD = "blah";
```

How can I do this? Where I can find the contract associated with the current salestable?

A bit more info

They are all a 1:1 relationship - so Contracttable is tied to 1 Customertable which is tied to 1 salestable

There is a LOT of data in my database thousands of entries - this query does not run constantly but does need to run somewhat efficent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    SalesTable a
        INNER JOIN CustomerTable b
            ON a.customerUUID = b.customerUUID
        INNER JOIN Contracttable c
            ON b.contractUUID = c.contractUUID
WHERE   c.variableD = 'valueHere'
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you sure the contract exists use this (othewise swap INNER FOR LEFT):

```
SELECT variableB, variableD
FROM Salestable t1
INNER JOIN Customertable t2 ON (t1.customerUUID = t2.customerUUID)
INNER JOIN Contracttable t3 ON (t3.contractUUID = t2.contractUUID)
WHERE variableD = "blah"
GROUP BY t1.variableB
```